# Change port number via command line in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I know how to change the port number via SQL Server Configuration Manager, but is there any way to do so via the command-line or sqlcmd?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the port via sqlcmd and I've never found a command line option. You can, however, do it via WMI. Check out [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/08/11/how-to-change-the-ip-all-tcp-port-to-a-static-port-from-a-dynamic-port-using-wmi.aspx) to get you started if you're interested in going that route.